# unable to install Shopify CLI on mac

Tags: ruby, shopify, homebrew

I installed Shopify CLI using homebrew.
The installation is ok.

I used the following steps:

1. `brew tap shopify/shopify`
2. `brew install shopify-cli`
3. `shopify version`

I can see that by typing `brew list` that shopify-cli is installed.
After the installation, I'm running `shopify version`

[image]

Expected behavior
I should get the shopify version

Actual behavior
I'm getting an unexpected error

[image]

Operating System: macOS

Shell: zsh

Ruby version (ruby -v): 3.0.3

[image]

Comment: what happens if you run `sudo shopify version`?

Comment: Now it's working.
Thank you for helping me after spending the entire day!!!
Is that mean that I need to use sudo every time?

Comment: Your Homebrew is majorly screwing you over if it is indeed installing software packages that require sudo. Your install should be going into /usr/local where your account owns anything executing in there, meaning you would not be required to sudo anything.